# changing the size of stencil during iterations within a for loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, iteration

I have a matrix [35rows x 39columns] of 2x1 column vectors, representing ordered pairs. I also have a function that creates a 9 point stencil and evaluates those points, then returns 9 values and picks the largest one. It then creates another 9 point stencil centered where the largest return value was located, and continues until the function terminates at the global maximum value in the matrix.

My question is, how can I make the stencil more efficient by disregarding points it has already evaluated? I don't want to evaluate 9 points every time because it will take longer, and I am trying to make this process as fast as possible.

Process:
1.) Evaluate a point and the 8 surrounding it,
2.) Pick largest of the return values,
3.) Move to that point,
4.) Repeat

I am referencing a cell, so I use {i,j} indexing.

---

Here's what I have for code:

```
for k = 1:10^(6)

            Setpoint1 = Field{i,j}(1);
            Setpoint1 = Field{i,j}(2);

            Setpoint2 = Field{i-1,j-1}(1);
            Setpoint2 = Field{i-1,j-1}(2);

            Setpoint3 = Field{i-1,j}(1);
            Setpoint3 = Field{i-1,j}(2);

            Setpoint4 = Field{i-1,j+1}(1);
            Setpoint4 = Field{i-1,j+1}(2);

            Setpoint5 = Field{i,j-1}(1);
            Setpoint5 = Field{i,j-1}(2);

            Setpoint6 = Field{i,j+1}(1);
            Setpoint6 = Field{i,j+1}(2);

            Setpoint7 = Field{i+1,j-1}(1);
            Setpoint7 = Field{i+1,j-1}(2);

            Setpoint8 = Field{i+1,j}(1);
            Setpoint8 = Field{i+1,j}(2);

            Setpoint9 = Field{i+1,j+1}(1);
            Setpoint9 = Field{i+1,j+1}(2);
```

From there I make 9 function calls, and record the rSquared value only (temp1 etc is an object with multiple fields, but I am only concerned with rSquared.)

```
            tempVec = [temp1.rSquared,temp2.rSquared,temp3.rSquared,temp4.rSquared,temp5.rSquared,temp6.rSquared,temp7.rSquared,temp8.rSquared,temp9.rSquared];
            nextCenter = find(tempVec==max(tempVec));

            if nextCenter == 1
                break;
            end

            if nextCenter == 2;
                i = i-1;
                j = j-1;
            elseif nextCenter == 3;
                i = i-1;
            elseif nextCenter == 4;
                i = i-1;
                j = j+1;
            elseif nextCenter == 5;
                j = j-1;
            elseif nextCenter == 6;
                j = j+1;
            elseif nextCenter == 7;
                i = i+1;
                j = j-1;
            elseif nextCenter == 8;
                i = i+1;
            elseif nextCenter == 9;
                i = i+1;
                j = j+1;
            end

            nextCenter = [];

    end
```

And Dan, I just found that out when comparing it to a different algorithm :( I can fix that, all I need help with is this stencil.

Comment: Your technique will not guarantee a global max

Comment: could you share some sample code?

Comment: So help me understand your problem better -- why not compute this rSquared value for every point once, storing all of them in some array, and just pick the largest? Also, did you notice that you're overriding each `Setpoint` variable with the second coordinate?

Comment: There are 1365 different combinations of points, with each one taking around 2-3 seconds to compute through a model. It took me anywhere between 30-40 minutes to execute the program, and I'd like to avoid that. The algorithm places the initial guess in the middle of the matrix at i = 18 and j = 20.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no more information available about the properties of your function (monotonicity would be nice) then there is not much better to do than just trying all possibilities.

At least make sure you only do everything once, but I guess that is trivial if you just go through all of them.

If you want performance, try `cellfun` it is a little more complicated than a loop but can probably give you the best speed.

---

If you are still looking for a way to make your heuristic more efficient, simply track your progress:

```
toBeEvaluated = true(35,39);
```

If you consider to evaluate a point, check whether it is still to be done. After evaluating simply set the value in the progress matrix to false.